# Parsing SQL query from URL request as JSON for jTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jtable

I am trying to create a jTable that uses data from a SQL Server stored procedure that I have the url for. I am having some issues parsing the data I'm getting back as JSON for the jTable to display.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="StaffingSummaryReport"></div>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#StaffingSummaryReport').jtable({
            title: 'Staffing Summary Report',
            paging: true,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'GVProject ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: staffingUtilities.baseUrl + 'Reports/GetStaffingSummaryReportDataNew/?startDate=2015-01-19'
            },
            fields: {
                GVProject: {
                    title: 'Project',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                ProjectManager: {
                    title: 'Project Manager',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                ProjectDivision: {
                    title: 'Division',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                StatusName: {
                    title: 'Status',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                Hours: {
                    title: 'Hours',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                ResourceName: {
                    title: 'Resource Need',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                StartDate: {
                    title: 'Start Date',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                EndDate: {
                    title: 'End Date',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                Notes: {
                    title: 'Notes',
                    width: '10%'
                }
            }
        });

        $('#StaffingSummaryReport').jtable('load');
    });
```

Here's my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetStaffingSummaryReportDataNew(DateTime startDate, string proDivisions = "", string staffingStatuses = "", string primaryCol = "project", string primarySort = "asc", string secondaryCol = "status", string secondarySort = "asc")
{
    var url = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GVStaffingSummaryReportApiUrl"], startDate, proDivisions, staffingStatuses, primaryCol, primarySort, secondaryCol, secondarySort);
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = stream, TotalRecordCount = 100 });
    }
}
```

I verified that the correct data is coming back from my HttpWebRequest. I'm getting an internal server error, but I verified that the URL being requested is correct, as it is being used elsewhere in the code. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what I can do better?

Comment: Please explain why you're having some issues.

Comment: I'm getting a script error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /" which tells me that the parsed JSON is invalid

Comment: No, you're parsing an URL as JSON. You may want to perform a request to the URL first, and parse the response.

Comment: I'm talking about listAction: $.parseJSON(staffingUtilities.baseUrl...

Comment: Okay I'm getting an internal server error when I remove the $.parseJSON(). But the path is definitely correct.